# Using Zend json server on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, zend-framework, json

I'm new to Magento 2 and I'm trying to create a module that uses Zend Json Server.

The initial code in the module controller was (in Magento 1):

```
public function postAction()
{
$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
    $client = new MyClientClass();
    $server->setClass($client);
    $server->handle();
}
```

How do I replace it in Magento 2?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many times I figured it out and thought to share.

```
$server = new \Zend\Json\Server\Server();
```